# Is there an API to obtain Solar System body axial tilt data?

Tags: rotation

I would like to get information about rotation period and axial tilt for main Solar System bodies and major moons, over time.

Is there an API availabe for this?

I've checked JPL's Horizons API and CSPICE toolkit, but as far as I've seen axial tilt and rotation period are constants, not values that can be retrieved for different points in time.

Comment: have you looked through https://github.com/public-apis/public-apis#science--math ? there might be something there...

Comment: Thank you for the link @AaronF. I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for there but definitely bookmarking it :).

Comment: Actually, I was completely wrong in my question, when I wrote that CSPICE does not provide this information. After checking Celestia's source code (https://github.com/CelestiaProject/Celestia/blob/master/src/celephem/spicerotation.cpp#L155), I realise that there's a bunch of functions in CSPICE that provide all the information, mainly: pxform_c (https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/C/cspice/pxform_c.html).